# Does a form review stage decrease submissions by robots?

Tags: forms, spam-prevention, captcha

A relatively recent change to (some?) SE sites is the `Review` button instead of submitting the question immediately.

I have always promoted a review stage. One benefit is that the user gets a chance to check over the submission, but I think that’s not so important, especially if you can edit the question anyway.

I have read that including a review stage is also helpful in reducing robots, since they don’t ordinarily hang around to submit the form a second time. That’s certainly why I encourage it, as it’s a much more user-friendly option than including Captcha, whose main purpose, it appears, is to help train Google’s AI and to annoy users.

Is the review stage effective in reducing robots?

Comment: Gonna use a comment instead of an answer for this but Bots are made by humans to achieve a task. If more and more CMS's forced review vs post and ability to edit afterwards I just feel like botmakers would adapt and add support for it. So while it might reduce bots now I feel the only reason is the ROI is not there for bot creater to add this support.... yet.

Comment: @Analog The same might be said for Captcha. Since bot can afford to fail and try again, it’s not hard to design it to take a stab and move on.

Comment: You're exactly right about Captcha. There are now plently of captcha solving services out there with API support for bot creators such as "DeathbyCaptcha", "AntiCaptcha", and others. So it seems that it has gotten to a point where it is worth it to the bot creators to just start including captcha solvers into the bots themselves.